# Magento Getting the URL for a Block phtml

Tags: php, magento, block

I'm writing a payment module and upon returning a successful authorisation from the server, I'd like to open a window with a template file in there to manage redirection to the payment service provider's authentication procedure.

How do I get the URL for the block's phtml file?
I want to run it into a JS function to open in a lightbox.

Comment: Magento doesn't work that way. Templates are Lego blocks that fill holes in other Lego block structures. Magento assembles all the blocks together to display them as a page. The URL is determined by the router being used from the assigned controller.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what exactly you want to achieve.

If you are for example in a specific action and you know the block which has the template you can do something like

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('specific_block')->getTemplate()
```

to return the template file of the current block
or

```
$template = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->getBlock('specific_block')->getTemplate();
```

Comment: I'm looking for the full, accessible URL of the template file. These methods only return /modulename/template.phtml

Comment: But with the content of the file you can open your lightbox and you got your phtml or do you want to tranfser this to the payment provider? Something like a backurl?